# Is there a way to autowire Generics in Java Interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-data-jpa

This is what I have. I am trying to autowire the JpaRepository so that I can access it in a generic way.

```
public interface Enabler<T, R> {

    @Autowired
    R repository;

    default ServiceEnabler<T> getEnabler(){
        return new ServiceEnabler<>(repository);
    }
}

public class User implements Enabler<User, UserRepository>, Serializeable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5454763392593161707L;

    Long id;
    String name;
}

@Repository
public UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByName();
}

@Service
public GenericService<T extends Enabler<T, R>,
                      R extends JpaRepository<T, Long>> {

    List<T> getAll(T generic){
        ServiceEnabler<T> enabler = generic.getEnabler();
        return enabler.getRepo().findAll();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway that this is possible?

Comment: This question makes no sense, since you cannot declare *instance fields* in an interface.

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of "Interface" in Java is to define a contract for all classes implementing the interface; "Interface" in Java cannot have any state, you can only have runtime constants or methods.

Now since interface cannot have any state so you cannot create instance variables like this `R repository;`.

Now coming to `@Autowired` annotation, that as well you cannot do because purpose of this annotation is to inject a object, now like I said earlier since Java Interface cannot have a state so there is no question of injecting an object.

So, overall answer is that you cannot do what you are trying to do and `@Autowired  R repository;` will result in compilation error.